# Colorbox Width Issue

Tags: jquery, width, colorbox

Im having an issue with a colorbox on a site im developing.

The colorbox element is being called as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.video').colorbox({width:'650px',height:'350px'});
});
```

a.video has a href to a page with only a video using flowplayer with a set width and height.

The problem is that no matter what I set the width as it remains no bigger than 559px. The height is fine, I can change the height to any pixel value and it will update. However the width of the colorbox wont go above 559px and this is too small to show the video.

I have tried setting the innerWidth but this made no difference. Any thoughts on what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Check if the CSS has max-width defined anywhere... The CSS that comes with colorbox plugin for the wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, the javascript config file that was already in place before I started work on the site, had a max width setting in it.

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.video').colorbox.resize({width:'650px',height:'350px'});
  });
```